# How to initialize firstChild so I don't get "x.firstChild is null or not an object"?

Tags: javascript

In my JSP/HTML I have this:

```
<div id="exampleLabel"> </div>
```

Then in my javascript section I have a function called from an onclick like this;

```
function changeLabel(){
    exampleLabel.firstChild.nodeValue = 'LABEL HAS CHANGED';
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, does nothing in Firefox and in IE an error on page appears saying

> exampleLabel.firstChild is null or not an object.

Ok I can take it that there was no firstChild so trying to do firstChild.ANYTHING would be a NPE, I can even take it that the other browsers don't just initialize it themselves like Chrome obviously does.

Question is, how do I initialize it myself so I can then go `.nodeValue = "blahblah"` on it?

Comment: Though less DOM-compliant, why not stick with `exampleLabel.innerHTML = 'LABEL HAS CHANGED';`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work in IE is that unlike all other major browsers, it doesn't create text nodes for whitespace in your HTML, hence your `<div>` that only contains a space has no child nodes in IE. I would suggest adding a text node manually, or changing an existing one.

Also, unless you've declared `exampleLabel` elsewhere, you're relying on a non-standard and rather icky feature of IE and Chrome that maps IDs of DOM elements to properties of the global object (i.e., you can refer to an element as a variable by its ID). This doesn't work in other browsers. What you should do instead is use `document.getElementById()`.

```
function changeLabel(labelText) {
    var exampleLabel = document.getElementById('exampleLabel');
    var child = exampleLabel.firstChild;
    if (!child) {
        child = document.createTextNode('');
        exampleLabel.appendChild(child);
    }
    child.nodeValue = labelText;
}

changeLabel('LABEL HAS CHANGED');
```

Comment: Ah I see, I had thought the Firefox issue was the same but it just wasn't blowing up with the error like IE. Cheers for pointing that out. Two issues in one!

Answer (score 3):

Create a textNode and then append it.

```
function changeLabel(){
    var textNode = exampleLabel.firstChild;
    if (!textNode) {
        textNode = document.createTextNode('foo');
        exampleLabel.appendChild(textNode);
    }
    textNode.nodeValue = 'LABEL HAS CHANGED';
}
```

Comment: @TimDown I know copying over exampleLabel and not spotting its a reference by ID from the global scope is an easy mistake to make but the answer is still incomplete. It is a grey area as to whether its valid for a downvote. Yes it is harsh but in this context you can recognize that the user was referring to exampleLabel by ID directly.